# Aren't async/await functions put in event loop?

Tags: javascript

I am very new to asynchronous Javascript and was studying the async/await feature. I have kind of a basic question about the code attached. When I run the code, I think the async function should wait (because of await keyword)  and be put in micro-task queue, thus suspending its execution. So, the call stack should execute the main thread's console.log('first') , then print the output of randomFunction() when call stack is empty and micro-task queue starts executing and finally invoke the callback. So I thought the output should've been first, (the random number) and then second. But to my surprise that isn't the case. Can someone please explain why this happened in a simplified manner ?

```js
function randomFunction() {
  //generates a random number and prints it
  const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  console.log(number);
}

async function asyncWithCallback(callback) {
  await randomFunction();
  callback();
}

function callback() {
  console.log('second');
}
asyncWithCallback(callback);
console.log('first');
```

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Type it and format it.

Comment: It's only put into the event loop if it actually does something asynchronous.

Comment: asynchronous functions are put into the callback queue in the call stack which is checked on every loop

Answer (score 1):

`await` first evaluates the expression that follows it, and only then the `async` function returns (with a promise), suspending the function for later.

So the output of the `randomFunction` is produced *synchronously*, and then it proceeds as you describe: "first" is output synchronously as well.

Then the call stack becomes empty and we arrive in the "asynchronous phase": the engine processes the job in the PromiseJob queue, which resumes the `async` function, which calls `callback` where "second" is output.